# Compile Error: Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement. at line 11 column 9

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, compile-error

I am not sure what is wrong in my code, but I get the following compile error:

> Error: Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement. at line 11 column 9

Below is my VF Page

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Revenue_Reports__c" extensions="VF_Controller_CasePgLayout" />
```

Below is my controller class

```
public with sharing class VF_Controller_FASPgLayout {

    public Revenue_Reports__c R1;

        public void VF_Controller_FASPgLayout(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            this.R1 = (Revenue_Reports__c)controller.getRecord();
        }

        public PageReference FASpageRedirect() {
            if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType') == '01I230000008cX9'){
                PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/RevenueReports_FAS_VfPge');
                return pageRef;
            }
            else if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccountId') == null){
                PageReference pageRef2 = new PageReference('https://cs28.salesforce.com/a4T/o');
                return pageRef2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what is that i am missing or why is this error message appearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basically the following structure in your `FASpageRedirect` method:

```
public pageReference myFunction()
{
    if (conditionA)
        return pageReferenceA;
    else if (conditionB)
        return pageReferenceB;
}
```

So what happens if neither `conditionA` nor `conditionB` are true? You need an unconditional return.

```
public pageReference myFunction()
{
    if (conditionA)
        return pageReferenceA;
    else if (conditionB)
        return pageReferenceB;
    return someFallbackPageReference; // you need a fallback plan
}
```

Also note that building your link using `cs28.salesforce.com` will not work when you deploy to your production environment, and likely won't even work during staging. You should construct your links more programmatically.

```
PageReference pageReferenceA = Page.RevenueReports_FAS_VfPge;
PageReference pageReferenceB = '/' + SObjectType.MyObject__c.getKeyPrefix() + '/o';
```

Replace `MyObject__c` above with the actual API Name of your object.